# IllegalArgumentException when using Otto with a retained Fragment

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, otto

I am using [Otto 1.3.3](http://square.github.io/otto/) and when I resume my application sometimes I get an `IllegalArgumentException` with the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Producer method for type class 
com.couchsurfing.mobile.ui.setup
        .SessionProviderFragment$SessionConnectionStateChangeEvent found on 
        type class com.couchsurfing.mobile.ui.setup.SessionProviderFragment, 
        but already registered by type class 
        com.couchsurfing.mobile.ui.setup.SessionProviderFragment.
    at com.squareup.otto.Bus.register(Bus.java:194)
    at com.couchsurfing.mobile.ui.BaseRetainedFragment
       .onCreate(BaseRetainedFragment.java:20)
```

The `SessionProviderFragment` has its instance retained, please find below the extended class:

```
public abstract class BaseRetainedFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Inject
    Bus bus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        ((CouchsurfingApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).inject(this);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bus.unregister(this);
        bus = null;
    }
}
```

I tried both using `bus.register(this)` in `onAttach()` or `onCreate()`, that didn't change the issue.

Comment: Just a thought - perhaps you are leaking the activity that hosts the fragment, such that in some cases (e.g. device rotation) you are creating a second instance of that activity, with a second instance of the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using one "Retained Fragment" per activity to save the state of an HTTP session request. My issue was that I didn't instantiate my "Retained Fragment" the proper way.

Before I had in onCreate():

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    sessionProviderFragment = new SessionProviderFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(sessionProviderFragment,
        SessionProviderFragment.TAG).commit();
}
```

Apparently the code above could create several `SessionProviderFragment` when quitting the activity is reopening it later. 
It seams that the correct way is :

```
sessionProviderFragment = (SessionProviderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag(SessionProviderFragment.TAG);

// If not retained (or first time running), we need to create it.
if (sessionProviderFragment == null) {
    sessionProviderFragment = new SessionProviderFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(sessionProviderFragment,
            SessionProviderFragment.TAG).commit();
}
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    initUiFragment();
}
```

I also moved the bus register/unregister in onResume/onPause in my BaseFragment to be sure that I will always have one `SessionProviderFragment` registered on the bus at a time.

Answer (score 7):

The proper place to register on the bus is in `onResume()` and the proper place to unregister is in `onPause()` like so:

```
public abstract class BaseRetainedFragment extends RoboSherlockFragment {
    @Inject private Bus bus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bus.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

Note that `onDestroy()` is [not guaranteed to be called](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

You might be about to comment on this and say, hey Chris, if I register in `onResume()` and and events are fired before I hit this method I won't receive the events! You would be right, but this means you aren't using [Producers](http://square.github.io/otto/) like you should be.

Also note, if you use [roboguice-sherlock](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rtyley/android/sherlock/roboguice/fragment/RoboSherlockFragment.java) you don't have to inject yourself. You also don't need to `null` the `Bus` when the Fragment goes out of scope the garbage collector will clean it up for you.

Comment: Regarding the comment about `onDestroy()`, Are you saying that otto may leak activities if we call `unregister` in `onDestroy`? When I read the docs for `onDestroy()`, I understand them to mean that onDestory should not be used for *saving* data, as the process may be spontaneously killed off/restarted (as seen the the activity lifecycle diagrams). In this case the activity (and otto) should all be released.

Comment: Apart from special purposes, don't ```register```/```unregister``` OttoBus during respective ```onResume``` -> ```onPause``` with fragment. I just found a loophole. If a dialog is shown over the fragment that supposedly receives bus events, the ```onPause()``` on the fragment will get called and unexpectedly unregister the OttoBus.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `Otto` and `EventBus` mostly to pass updates from background services to `Activities` and `Fragments`. I don't know your exact use case, but the most common use for me was to update the UI (e.g. `ProgressBar`, `status message`, etc).

Having said that, what I've found as most efficient, is to register the bus in the `onViewCreated()` method of the fragment and unregister it in the `onDestroyView()` method. Provided that the bus messages are persistent (via a `provider` for Otto or `sticky` events for `EventBus`), you will not lose any messages this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really safe to have an `@Produce` on a `Fragment`, because *more than one instance* of the fragment can exist (and be registered on the bus) at the same time.

In my opinion `@Produce` really only makes sense on a `singleton`.